# lodash - order dates with skipping year value

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs, lodash

```
var dates = ['2017-02-01', '2017-01-01', '2016-02-03', '2018-02-02', '2014-12-25'];
var orderedDates = dates.sort(); // ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2018-02-02', '2016-02-03', '2014-12-25']
```

I have collection of dates(moment objects) from different year. I need to sort this dates only by 'ddMM' format (like skip years).

Is there any way to do this?

create copy of `dates` array, set same year for all dates - not seem like good solution.

for sorting use lodash `.orderBy`

Comment: if you want to perform sort on date and month only then you have to separate year and ddMM. and then perform sort on ddMM. but you have to track the year also while performing sort on ddMM. so you have to create an obj type date. then you have to use _.orderBY on ddMM property. you will get sorted array of date objects.

Comment: I just created this, if you have already tried this means then skip. `var _ = require('lodash')
var dates = ['2017-02-01', '2017-01-01', '2016-02-03', '2018-02-02'];
var o = dates.map((d)=> {
    var s = d.split("-")
    return {
        year: s[0],
        ddMM: s[1] + "-" + s[2]
    }
}) 
console.log(_.orderBy(o, ['ddMM'], ['asc']))`

Comment: @varatharajan hm, thx, will check

Comment: Can you please add to your question the expected output?

Comment: @Akrion it's like comment in code lines

Comment: @demo but the input (as per the example) is a string array right? instead of a moments object array

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee input - moment objects... don't know how to show dates in example as moment objects, so show as strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the 'MMDD' format and not 'DDMM'.

And it is not necessary to convert it back to a moment, since it is just to sort the array.

```
var orderedDates = _.orderBy(dates, e => moment(e).format('MMDD'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderBy` with an array of functions that specify your desired order (where the functions get the `date` and `month` from the `moment` object):

```js
const date = (s) => moment(s, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
const dates = [date('2017-02-01'), date('2017-01-01'), date('2016-02-03'), date('2018-02-02'), date('2014-12-25')];

const result = _.orderBy(dates, [m => m.date(), m => m.month()]);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @demo I believe this is your desired order: `['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2018-02-02', '2016-02-03', '2014-12-25']`, which is what I get when I run the snippet?

Comment: what I see `[
  "2016-12-31T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2017-01-31T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2018-02-01T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-02-02T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2014-12-24T22:00:00.000Z"
]`

Comment: @demo That is quite strange. I created a fiddle and I get the correct output in the console: https://jsfiddle.net/481qypvr/ Anyways, no worries if you already have your answer.

Comment: hmmm, strange... maybe some bug on stack :D Cause I run code from your snippet and get result that I posted above... not I see that `2016-12-31T22:00:00.000Z` even not present in input array... so don't know